# How do I do a semijoin using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin

Let's say that I have two tables:  A and B.  I want to make a query that would work similarly to the following SQL statement using the SQLAlchemy orm:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id
AND B.type = 'some type';
```

The thing is that I'm trying to separate out A and B's logic into different places.  So I'd like to make two queries that I can define in separate places:  one where A uses B as a subquery, but only returns rows from A.  I'm sure this is fairly easy to do, but an example would be nice if someone could show me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have models classes `A` and `B` mapped to corresponding tables.

The simplest case is when you have relation in `A` pointing to `B`, let's name it `A.b`. Then you just use either `A.b.has(type='some type')` or `A.b.any(type='some type')` (depending on whether `A.b` is scalar or represent a collection) as condition when querying `A` model.

But you say you are trying to separate login. Does this mean there is no such relation? If so,  you have to define join condition explicitly:

```
session.query(A).join((B, A.id==B.id)).filter(B.type=='some type')
```

Comment: The logic for `B` is a bit more complex than the example I gave, and is something that will be used in other parts.  However, I think this gives me an idea of what to do to make this work.